# udev rules with systemctl do no longer work as expected

Tags: linux, usb, systemd, udev

I wrote two `udev` rules which worked fine until the introduction of `systemctl`.

These rules run a daemon whenever a kind of USB device is plugged in and stop the same daemon when the same device is unplugged. This is done with an helper script `myscript`.

With `systemctl` the problem now is that it apparently kills the daemon invoked by `myscript` after some seconds the device is plugged in.

The rules are the following:

- SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device",
                ENV{VID_PID}="%s{idVendor}:%s{idProduct}", ACTION=="add",
                RUN+="/etc/init.d/myscript plug %E{VID_PID}"`
- SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="remove", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device",
  ENV{VID_PID}="%E{ID_VENDOR_ID}:%E{ID_MODEL_ID}",
  RUN+="/etc/init.d/myscript unplug %E{VID_PID}"`

Note that the `myscript` accepts two arguments: the action *plug* or *unplug* and the device identifiers.

Do you know how to fix the problem or how to implement the same - if necessary - in terms of `systemctl`?

Answer (score 1):

As the `systemd.device` man page says, write a unit file for your service, and then tag the device with `"systemd"` and then use the `SYSTEMD_WANTS` property to start the unit. Do not use the `RUN` property for long-running processes.

Comment: how do i pass *the exact* arguments VID and PID to the systemd unit?